# VSCode Vim Addon: How do I set up Insert mode to basicity be normal VSCode (Vim disabled)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I love the keyboard shortcuts offered in Vim Normal mode and find them very helpful but I also like the keyboard shortcuts in normal VSCode. For example all the multi-cursor stuff. like ctrl+d (highlight next occurrence) or ctrl+f2: (highlight all occurrences).  For some reason whenever I use ctrl+d or ctrl+f2 it appears to work normally but puts me in visual mode even though I have turned off mouse selection goes into Visual mode.

TL/DR: Basically I just want Vim to act like it is off when in Insert mode but still allow me to go to normal mode with Escape

### Current Settings/Preferences

##### User/settings.json:

```
    "vim.useCtrlKeys": false, //appears to not work for me, I just removed bindings for some stuff with ctrl keys
    "vim.startInInsertMode": true,
    "vim.mouseSelectionGoesIntoVisualMode": false,
    "vim.smartRelativeLine": true,
    "vim.useSystemClipboard": true,
```

##### User/keybindings.json:

(minus sign in front of command means it is disabled):

```
    {
        "key": "shift+alt+down",
        "command": "-extension.vim_cmd+alt+down",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+alt+up",
        "command": "-extension.vim_cmd+alt+up",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+d",
        "command": "-extension.vim_ctrl+d",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && vim.use<C-d> && !inDebugRepl"
    }
```

##### OS: Windows 11 (don't bully me plz)

Answer (score 2):

You can change in vscode settings json.
Just insert this:

```
 "vim.startInInsertMode": true,
```